# Error in Panda dataframe types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am reading a csv file using pandas dataframes.
contents of test-data.log

```
name 1 2 3
value 4 5 6
type int float char
```

I use this script to read the file

```
import pandas as pd
url = "/usr/local/test-data.log"

dataframe = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\t', header=None)
df.dtypes
```

output I get is all entries are of type object, where it has to be int, int, object

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not tab delimited correctly. Looks like you have spaces instead of tabs. In your case each row is a string, ie the data in the first row is

`name 1 2 3`

You only have 1 column, instead of 4. That is why your seeing it as an object.

This is what your file should look like:

```
name    1   2   3
value   4   5   6
```

Once you run `df.types` on your data frame you will see 4 columns and 2 rows.

```
0    object
1     int64
2     int64
3     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. You have space-separated data, not tab-separated.
2. If any value in a column is non-numeric, it will likely be read in as `object` type. This makes sense, since the series type chosen must accommodate all values in the series. `object` represents a series of pointers, which can handle arbitrary types.

Issue (1) can be resolved by using `delim_whitespace=True`.

Issue (2) can be resolved by excluding the final line via `skipfooter=1`.

Here's a demo:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""StringIOname 1 2 3
value 4 5 6
type int float char""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, skipfooter=1)

print(df.dtypes)

0    object
1     int64
2     int64
3     int64
dtype: object
```